# connect to or connects to

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Which one is correct?

> the client connect to the server

Or

> the client connects to the server

Since client is singular, I assume there should be `s` after the verb. But the following `to` makes `connect to` sounds familiar to me. Can you help m please?

Comment: You have to use subject-verb agreement. As you said, if client is singular, it requires **connects**, which is singular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *'to'* has nothing to do with subject verb agreement. The subject is singular, so you put 's' to the verb in this case.

> The client connects to the server

and...

> The clients connect to the server